# Subquery return more than one value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle8i

I have the following query which gives gives `req_no and order_no`. `order_no` is a from a sub_query which you can see from below sql. For a few `req_no` there are more than one `order_no's` and because of that I get `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`.

I would like to display both the `order_no` for one `req_no`, how can I achieve this?
Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

P.S. Our client's one database is still `Oracle 8i`.

```
SELECT  max_qst.req_no,
            (SELECT  DISTINCT max_odr.order_no
                FROM     maximo_orders max_odr,
                         maximo_order_revisions max_odv,
                         maximo_order_items max_odi,
                         maximo_order_dates max_odd,
                         maximo_requisition_order max_rqo,
                         maximo_requisition_details max_req
              WHERE       max_req.req_no = max_qst.req_no
                         AND max_req.req_yr = max_qst.req_yr
                         AND max_odr.order_no = max_odi.order_no
                         AND max_odi.order_item_id = max_odd.order_item_id
                         AND max_req.requisition_item_id = max_rqo.requisition_item_id
                         AND max_rqo.order_schedule_id = max_odd.order_schedule_id
                         AND max_odv.order_no = max_odi.order_no
                         AND max_odv.revision_no =
                                 (SELECT   MAX (max_alias.revision_no)
                                     FROM   maximo_order_revisions max_alias
                                    WHERE   max_alias.order_no = max_odv.order_no)
                         AND maximo_order_item (max_odi.order_no,
                                                                  max_odv.revision_no,
                                                                  max_odi.order_item_id
                                                                 ) = 'CONFIRMED'
                        )
  FROM  maximo_requisitions max_qst, maximo_requisition_details max_qsd
 WHERE       max_qst.qst_id = max_qsd.qst_id
            AND max_qst.enter_date = '2001'
            AND max_qst.req_no = 'PUR_12WX'
```

*`Update 1`*

Desired out put.

```
REQ_No     ORDER_NO

PUR_12WX   PR_9078  
PUR_12WX   PR_9079
```

Comment: Do you care whether the `order_no` is a random one or are you looking for some sort of decisioning? To get a random one just use `max` or `min`. If you don't want the max or min this may be indicative of you not normalising your database correctly.

Comment: What behaviour do you want? If one `req_no` is associated to more than one `order_no`, do you want to show more than one row? *(`req_no` will be repeated on each row for each different `order_no`)*  Or do you just want to pick one of the `order_no` records?  And if so, which one?  `MIN()`, `MAX()`, something else?  A good idea is to create example data and show the exact result set you want.

Comment: Also, are you sure your joins in that sub-query are correct? As it looks like are actually after the maximum... if you get downvoted for doing this in a sub-query instead of a `join` don't worry too much, and also you should probably be using the explicit join syntax.

Comment: "Our client's one database is still Oracle 8i" - Crikey! You should point out that 8i is long out of support and they should upgrade to a DB version from this century.

Comment: @Dems Yes one `req_no` is associated to more than one `order_no` and I would like to display both `order_no` for one `req_no`.  Thanks

Comment: @Dems I have added desired output above as update 1. Thanks

Comment: In that case, use a join as I and other have suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join instead of a correlated sub-query.

I've removed the `max_qst` references from the sub-query and moved them to the join predicate.

I've also just changed it to use a `LEFT JOIN`.  This allows for the possibility of there being no `order_no` values returned.

```
SELECT
  max_qst.req_no,
  sub_query.order_no
FROM
  maximo_requisitions          max_qst
INNER JOIN
  maximo_requisition_details   max_qsd
    ON max_qst.qst_id = max_qsd.qst_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    max_odr.order_no,
    max_req.req_no,
    max_req.req_yr
  FROM
    maximo_orders              max_odr,
    maximo_order_revisions     max_odv,
    maximo_order_items         max_odi,
    maximo_order_dates         max_odd,
    maximo_requisition_order   max_rqo,
    maximo_requisition_details max_req
  WHERE
        max_odr.order_no            = max_odi.order_no
    AND max_odi.order_item_id       = max_odd.order_item_id
    AND max_req.requisition_item_id = max_rqo.requisition_item_id
    AND max_rqo.order_schedule_id   = max_odd.order_schedule_id
    AND max_odv.order_no            = max_odi.order_no
    AND max_odv.revision_no         = (SELECT MAX (max_alias.revision_no)
                                         FROM maximo_order_revisions max_alias
                                        WHERE max_alias.order_no = max_odv.order_no)
    AND maximo_order_item (max_odi.order_no,  max_odv.revision_no, max_odi.order_item_id) = 'CONFIRMED'
)
  suq_query
    ON  max_qst.req_no = sub_query.req_no
    AND max_qst.req_yr = sub_query.req_yr
WHERE
  max_qst.enter_date = '2001'
  max_qst.req_no = 'PUR_12WX'
```

Comment: I am getting SQL command not properly ended error when I execute this. What could be the reason for this? May be this is because I am running this in oracle 8i?  Thanks.

Comment: It does looks like the problem is with the Oracle version. The same query when I tried on oracle 10g was not giving SQL command not properly ended error, instead only giving table names were not found errors. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
DISTINCT
```

or

```
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

But I'd suggest you investigate *why* you're getting more than one row returned: Have you misunderstood the data, have you missed a join, is there erroneous or duplicate data etc etc.

Comment: The reason for more than one row is due to fact that one `order_no` status is `EXPORTED` and second one being `IN_PROGRESS`. I would like to have both. Thanks

Comment: How and where to use `WHERE ROWNUM = 1`. Thanks

Comment: The example already does use `DISTINCT`, so you actually have imperical evidence supplied to you to make that suggestion void.  The use of `ROWNUM=1` also should have an explanation of why it would solve the error and the implications of doign so.  *(The OP seems to **imply** that the 1:many relationship is correct, and so just picking one record may mask the issue rather than resolve it.)*

Comment: I was offering a general suggestion about why that error occurs and how you might get round it. Without knowing a little more about the structure of the tables and the data it is difficult to suggest an exact fix. Any DBA would tell you a cartesian is difficult to resolve without knowledge of both...